# How can I flip an array when each value is also an array?

Tags: php, arrays

How would I go about flipping an array and establishing relationships between all the values and keys? For example:

I am trying to turn this:

```
Array ( 
[11913] => Array ( 
            [0] => 4242 
            [1] => 3981 
    ) 
[9878] => Array ( 
            [0] => 2901 
            [1] => 3981 
    ) 
[11506] => Array ( 
            [0] => 3981 
            [1] => 2901 
    ) 
 )
```

Into this:

```
Array ( 
    [3981] => Array ( 
            [0] => 11506 
            [1] => 9878 
            [2] => 11913 
        ) 
    [2901] => Array ( 
            [0] => 11506 
            [1] => 9878 
        ) 
    [4242] => Array ( 
            [0] => 11913 
        ) 
     )
```

Are there any PHP functions that will already do this automatically? If not what would be a way of going about this? Can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: I think you're going to have to brute-force this approach.  With any luck, I am wrong about this.

Comment: try some combination of array_walk and array_flip, or check out the multi_array_flip function given in the comments at
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go.

```
$final_array = array();
foreach($initial_array as $key => $val){
    foreach($val as $v){
        $final_array[$v][] = $key;
    }
}
```

Comment: the $val is an array in his $initial_array example, isn't it?

Comment: $val are the second level arrays in the $initial_array, yes.

Comment: oh when you don't specify that in foreach it will just grab the value, as we don't need those keys.. i think i get it :)